# Terraform: remote module not following providers block - Warning: Reference to undefined provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt, terraform-modules

I'm trying to use a (private) remote terraform module, and trying to pass a different provider to it. For the remote module, there are no providers defined and to my understanding, it will use a the local provider instead.

I can't seem to be able to get it to use a provider alias - there are a few files at play here:

```
# main.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region

}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "replica_region"
  region = var.replica_region
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}
```

```
# s3.tf
module "some-remote-module" {
  source = 'git::ssh.......'
  providers = {
    aws = aws.replica_region
  }
}
```

Whenever I plan (with terragrunt), The region is that of the primary aws provider config. I get the following warning, too:

```
│ Warning: Reference to undefined provider
│
│   on s3.tf line 12, in module "some-remote-module":
│   12:     aws = aws.replica_region
│
│ There is no explicit declaration for local provider name "aws" in
│ module.some-remote-module, so Terraform is assuming you
│ mean to pass a configuration for "hashicorp/aws".
│
│ If you also control the child module, add a required_providers entry named
│ "aws" with the source address "hashicorp/aws".
╵
```

Am I passing the providers in incorrectly? Is this even something that terraform is capable of? I'm using terraform 1.3. The remote module doesn't have any provider config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last paragraph of this message is suggesting that you modify the child module to include the following declaration so that it's explicit that when you say "aws" it means `hashicorp/aws` rather than a provider in some other namespace that might coincidentally also be called "aws":

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what the error message means by `a required_providers entry named "aws" with the source address "hashicorp/aws"`.

This allows Terraform to see for certain (rather than guessing) that the short name "aws" refers to the same provider in both the calling module and the called module.

Comment: this doesn't works for me. no luck even after running `tf init` command again.